# Ordenar un arrglo con base a otro arreglo

Tags: array, c

Tengo un arreglo unidimensional (Arreglo1) donde almaceno numero que van de 3 al 9 de forma aleatoria. En otro arreglo unidimensional (Arreglo2) tengo almacenado los indices de cada valor del Arreglo1. Ahora, yo estoy ordenando el Arreglo1, con el método de burbuja, de forma descendente (de 9 a 3). Mi problema es que necesito ordenar los valores del Arreglo2 de tal forma que cada valor que esta en este coincida con el valor que tenia en el Arreglo1. NOTA: estoy trabajando en lenguaje C.

```
for( x = 0; x < tamaioDelArreglo2; x++ ){
        indices [ x ] = x;
    }
```

Arreglo2 optiene sus valores

```
       for( x = 0; x < tamanioTablero; x++ ){
        
        if( x < pmi ){
            tablero [x] = rand () % ( 9 - 2 + 1 ) + 2;
            
        }else if ( x >= pmi && x <= pmd ) {
            tablero [x] = 1;
            
        }else{
            tablero [x] = 0;
        }
        
    }
```

Toda esta parte es donde el Arreglo1 toma sus valores

```
for ( y = 1; y < tamaioDelArreglo2 ; y++ ){
            
                //guardamos el valor en aux para moverlo de Lugar
                aux = tablero [y];
                x = y - 1;
            
                 //mientras esto de cumpla seguria moviendolo a indice anterior
                 while( (x >= 0) && (aux > tablero [x]) ){
                    cont++;
                    tablero [x + 1] = tablero [x];
                    x--;    
                }
                //cuadno termine de moverlo se almacena
                tablero [x + 1] = aux;
             
    }
```

Aquí ordeno Arreglo1

Lo que he intentado es crear un arreglo bidimensional donde se almacene los incides y los valores, para cuando llegue el momento del ordenamiento poder ordenar ambos, pero solo tomando en cuenta los valores de 9 a 3.

Comment: Hola, gimEr. Bienvenido a stackoverflow en español. ¿Podrías, por favor, editar tu pregunta añadir un ejemplo y lo que has intentado? De esta forma podemos ayudarte con lo que necesitas.

Comment: Ya puedes revisarlo nuevamente

Comment: Creo que te falta código relevante, hay muchas variable que ne veo donde las define (no sé el valor). Ejemplo de esto son `tamaioDelArreglo2` y `pmi`. Tampoco veo donde iniciálizas cada arreglo. ://

Comment: Si ya has encontrado una solución, lo suyo es escribir la respuesta... como si fuese una respuesta en vez de añadirla a la pregunta

Comment: Deje tu pregunta como estaba, porque si tenes una respuesta debe ir en el campo respuesta. La respuesta debe estar bien explicada de cual era el problema y como se solucionaba...